# How do I write 10 raised to 9 (10^9) in an if-statement not using Math.Pow? C#

Tags: c#, math, integer

I'm new to this so sorry if this question already have been answered.

I am writing a program in c# and I'm trying to make an if-statement where an integer cannot be higher than 10 raised to 9 (10^9) and not below or equivalent to 0. I tried to search for it and found that I perhaps can use the Math.Pow(10,9) but I don't see how I can do that in the if-statement? Now I have only tried to compile the code while writing a big number, but it's supposed to be 10 raised to 9 and I don't know how to write it?

Here's the code:

```
if (C > 100000 || C <= 0)
```

Comment: Assuming that `C` is the name of the variable you are testing, you could use `if (C <= 0 || C > Math.Pow(10, 9))`

Comment: You can use the floating point value `10e9` instead of `1000000000`: `if (c > 10e9 || c <= 0)`

Comment: Be aware though that using `Math.Pow(10, 9`) or `10e9` will produce a `double`.  That may or may not be what you want

Comment: Martin is correct, but note that `10e9` won't fit in an `int` - it would have to be a `long`. So when you say `an integer cannot be higher than 10 raised to 9 (10^9)` then I assume you mean `integral type`. If you're actually using `int` then it cannot be greater than 10e9.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure all I know is that the task says "The first line contains two integers C and n (1 < C < 10^9, 2 < n < 100). You can ignore the integer n, just showing the task. But I'm thinking if it's possible to first declare an integer C and then convert it to long and make the Math or floating part?

Comment: If you start off with `int` then it's not possible for it to exceed `10e9` so there would be no point in converting it to `long` and then comparing it with `10e9`.

Comment: But I was thinking to start off as an int, then convert it to a long en then doing the if-statement where it cannot be higher than 10e9?

Comment: the task is either a trick question, or the one who wrote the excercise meant use the word integer as a synonym for a whole number. So the choice of the datatype is yours. Use a `long`, write in a comment that as you have learnt using `int` would not make any sense because it cannot exceed 10 to the power of 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to validate if a number is between 10^9 and 0

```
  if (Math.Pow(10, 9) >= C &&  C > 0)
      Console.WriteLine("valid");
  else
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
```